# Excel find records which are not matched in another list

Tags: excel

I've a first table (let's call it A) with a column URL which contains some values which are not unique.

There is a second table (let's call it B) which is similar to A.

I want to evidence the records of A which have an URL that is not on B.

Comment: How are you looking to do this?  Various solutions in VBA and many with regular excel formulas.  Could probably just use VLookups

Comment: Or a simple COUNTIF()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, your columns `A:A` and `B:B` have URL lists you want to compare. Add column headers in top row, if you have none. Then write this formula in `C2` and drag it down:

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B,$A1)=0
```

Then select the whole column `C:C` by clicking on gray `C` header above topmost cell and apply filter by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Filter by `TRUE` - these are the values you need.

Comment: And if I don't want TRUE - FALSE in cell C? The most elegant is using an IF?

Comment: Yes, it can be done using `=IF()`: `=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A1)=0,"yes","no")`.